# Какая разница между инициалиизацией в классе(поле) и в конструкторе?

Tags: c#

Скажите пожалуйста, какая разница между инициалиизацией в классе(поле) и в конструкторе в c#?

Например:

```
    class Test
{
ErrorsTest valueErr=new ErrorsTest();
...
}
```

И:

```
    class Test{
ErrorsTest valueErr;
 public Test()
    {
    valueErr=new ErrorsTest;
    }
}
```

Comment: В первом случае инициализация произойдёт до вызова любого конструктора

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746890/10105